# How did the belt system color develop?

Tags: belt

I was told that a student of martial arts  started with a white belt and used the same belt throughout their training and that they never washed the belt so over time it became darker and eventually black and that the current belt system is based join this graduation from light to dark.

Is this how the modern belt system developed?

Comment: The *not washing your belt* is an urban myth that even a slight knowledge of Japanese culture (or any other culture for that matter) can prove as utter rubbish.  A variation (still utter rubbish) is the dying the belt with darker and darker colours.

Comment: Actually was started by founder of Judo for training children and allowing them some form to see their progression. Was later adapted by other martial arts for adults and children